# Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 Login Loop Problem

Tags: login

recently I decided to download and dualboot Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 with Windows 10, so far so good it worked and my primarily reasons for this distribution was gaming (csgo) and testing some stuff.
Afterwards, I decided to download Metasploit & Kali Linux Tools using the following sources below. My Metasploit wouldn't work properly and kept giving me errors, so I looked up those errors and as a conclusion, I decided to restart my pc.
That was obviously a bad choice. Now whenever I try log in, my monitor(s) ~ 3 monitors keeps flickering black and white a few seconds, and then it just returns me back to the login screen, eventually stays in a login loop.

Sources: 
Metasploit: http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-in-ubunt/

Kali Linux Tools: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8G3XbSniBqA

BTW:
I HAVE looked at other posts, but I'm not authorized to comment there and ask for help, (I need atleast 50+ comments or reputation or whatever).

And for the record, I don't have a file called "Xauthority".

Thanks in advance!